enable webnn support in electron
I'm trying to use webnn in electron with GPU support
Samples run correctly in my machine if I use latest chrome
But in electron based app, window.ml does not exists
I've tried all ways to enable it:
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-blink-features', 'WebNN');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-webnn')`
enableBlinkFeatures: "WebNN",
enableBlinkFeatures: [
        "experimental-web-machine-learning-neural-network",
        "web-machine-learning-neural-network"      
      ]

any suggestion?

This is not a full solution, but an explanation of how to (hopefully) achieve one.
Most likely, window.ml is being made available, but is only being made available in the preload script.
You can try disabling sandbox and enabling nodeIntegration to prove that window.ml then becomes available. If it does, then you'll need to do the relevant logic in your preload script instead. See docs

Also be sure that app.commandLine.appendSwitch is being called before app.whenReady occurs. I'd advise testing with passing the CLI args directly when you run Electron rather than via app.commandLine for the to be entirely sure it's being applied properly.
Do not use nodeIntegration: true in production - use preload instead if this proves to make window.ml available.

nodeIntegreation:true is not an option in production

chrome://gpu show the correct flags (enableFeatures) has been applied

I don't understand your reply. I suggested nodeIntegration for debugging purposes. Did you try it? If enabling it exposes window.ml then I can give you further advice.

Node integration is not an option. window.ml cannot be exposed from node

Your responses are unclear and you're not going to get any help if you don't help people to help you.
